# How to create a paragraph that show the number of line it contains?

Tags: line-breaking, paragraphs, primitives

Trying being brief...

How can I create a paragraph that shows meta information, e.g., mentioning the number of lines or words it contains, using **TeX primitives** only? It's very important that such information could appear at any place in the paragraph (at the start, middle or end... anywhere in the paragraph)

For example:

> This paragraph has 4 lines. Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá-Blá

(I'm not sure if the paragraph above will be coherent. That is the point in this question!)

I've thought about create a \vbox, do some calculations and unbox it after updates. But a meta data could occupying a lot of lines. I have no idea how to preview where TeX system will break a line o use hyphenation, so, how many lines will be add after the insertion of a some characters at a given point.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the number is available after the paragraph do you need to put it at the start (that requires multiiple passes especially as inserting that text may increase the line count)

Comment: after it is easy: `..... bla <blank line> the last para had \the\prevgraf\ lines.`

Comment: Reading in Tex Reference Manual by David Bausum, it seems complicated to apply it. In my actual understanding, it's yet not applicable to the problem. Tex need to "eat" succeeding lines before evaluating the value and writing it. If useful, only at the end of the paragraph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do measurement of lines in the `\setbox0=\vbox` context:

```
\newcount\linenum
\def\linecount #1\par{%
   \linenum=0
   \setbox0=\vbox{#1\par\global\linenum=\prevgraf}%
   \setbox0=\vbox{#1\par\global\linenum=\prevgraf}%
   #1\par
}
\def\lines{\the\linenum}

\linecount The paragrpaph has \lines\ lines. 
Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá
Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá
Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá
Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá
Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá
Blá Blá Blá Blá Blá

\end
```

I do this measurement two times because the number of lines can be changed when the digits of the `\linenum` register is known.

Note, that `\newcount` is not TeX primitive. If you need only TeX primitives, then use `\countdef`. All other constructions are TeX primitive only.

Comment: Note that paragraphs do not always end with a \par or blank line; e.g. \end{document}.

Comment: Yes, I know. For example `\end` primitive produces `\par` only when it is processed and it is in horizontal mode. This is the reason why I added empty line before `\end` in my example. The syntax of usage `\linecount` macro is: you have to use explicit \par or empty line at the end of the paragraph.

Comment: You've hit the point... I was attempt to avoid performing the same calculation/algorithm two times but.. looking the direct way you resolved I am convinced that is needed.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `\label` and `\ref`, or an equivalent concept. Two passes are necessary, because `\prevgraf` is not available until the final `\par` closing the paragraph has been processed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{countpar}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\lines}{%
  % redefine \par to do the count
  \stepcounter{countpar}%
  \def\par{%
    \@@par % finish the paragraph
    \edef\@currentlabel{\the\prevgraf}%
    \label{lines@\thecountpar}%
    \let\par\@@par
  }%
  This paragraph has~\textbf{\ref{lines@\thecountpar}} lines%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lines.
Some text follows. Some text follows. Some text follows.
Some text follows. Some text follows. Some text follows.
Some text follows. Some text follows. Some text follows.
Some text follows. Some text follows. Some text follows.
Some text follows. Some text follows. Some text follows.
Some text follows. Some text follows. Some text follows.

\lines.
Some text follows. Some text follows. Some text follows.
Some text follows. Some text follows. Some text follows.
Some text follows. Some text follows. Some text follows.
Some text follows. Some text follows. Some text follows.

Some text follows. Some text follows. Some text follows.
Some text follows. Some text follows. Some text follows.
\lines.
Some text follows. Some text follows. Some text follows.
Some text follows. Some text follows. Some text follows.

Some text follows. Some text follows. Some text follows.
Some text follows. Some text follows. Some text follows.
Some text follows. Some text follows. Some text follows.
Some text follows. Some text follows. Some text follows.
Some text follows. Some text follows. Some text follows.
Some text follows. Some text follows. Some text follows.
Some text follows. Some text follows. Some text follows.
Some text follows. Some text follows. Some text follows.
Some text follows. Some text follows. Some text follows.
\lines.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well. It's done, but using some not TeX primitives. Except by label, I could reproduce the commands in Pure TeX. How to create a Label command to perform such task?

Comment: @DanielBandeira: You can pull the relevant `\label` definition (and others) from the LaTeX kernel ([`latex.ltx`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co)) if you wish to boil it down more.